# What is the default field Modifier in Java class?

Tags: java, reflection, field, access-modifiers

In the following code, field1 does not have a modifier: public/protected/private

```
public class class1 {
    String field1;
}
```

So what is the modifier of field1?

In the Modifier definition in Java, these are all the Modifiers that are relevant to a field:

```
    Modifier.PUBLIC         | Modifier.PROTECTED    | Modifier.PRIVATE |
    Modifier.STATIC         | Modifier.FINAL        | Modifier.TRANSIENT |
    Modifier.VOLATILE;
```

Which of the modifier(s) does field1 have? I feel it does not have any of  Modifier.PUBLIC,Modifier.PROTECTED, and Modifier.PRIVATE

I ask this because I want to access this field one via Java reflection.

---

Thanks. For the answers.

It indeed has no modifier.

I have tested getModifiers() for field1. It returns 0.

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't have any modifier.

Comment: Why does it *need* to have a modifier? From the source code, it does *not* have a modifier...

Comment: The modifier is a bit mask and 0 or none is a valid option.  BTW The default modifier in other contexts is different.

Comment: [Access modifiers in JAVA.](http://java8.in/unit-1-concept-1-access-modifiers-in-java/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has no modifier. For further details what this lack of modifier means see here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 1):

Its modifier is known as `default`. It is every variable/function's modifier that does not explicitly tell about any other modifier.

Answer (score 0):

There is no modifiers. You can access to field from class, package, but not from subclass or another package.

Answer (score 0):

It dose have modifier--default, which is always implict. A field or a method modified with default is accessable to classes that share the same package with the field or method.